# Unable to run nunit 3.0 tests from teamcity

Tags: teamcity, nunit-3.0

Trying to run nunit3.0 tests in teamcity. It works fine if I use anyother nunit version. I am using the following configuration to run tests. Can you please advise what I am missing here.
 [image]

Teamcity is throwing the following error:-

```
 [10:04:39][Step 3/3] 2) Error : UI.AutomationTest.SmokeTests

 [10:04:39][Step 3/3] System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

 [10:04:39][Step 3/3]   ----> System.Exception : No application configuration found for GRP and environment Dev.
```

Problem is with relative paths. Nunit3.0 console is not supporting any relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you mis the rest of the path to the executable.

You have:

> C:\WebDrivers\NUnit-3.0.0\bin\

Likely you should have:

> C:\WebDrivers\NUnit-3.0.0\bin\nunit3-console.exe

In [this blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2015/11/teamcity-and-nunit-3/) you'll find a reference to how it could be done.

Comment: While link may give all the necessary information, links may break over time, so please quote or mention the most relevant parts inside your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your build is not working, are you passing a .dll in to that bottom input?

I have been able to setup running tests with NUnit and have details on my blog of how I did it, there may be something along the way that you did differently?
[**link**](http://thesneakytester.com/2015/09/25/running-parallel-automation-tests-using-nunit-v3/)

Otherwise, here is the official TeamCity documentation that came out last month about setting it up that might help also:
[**link**](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Getting+Started+with+NUnit)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.